# Gnuplot: multiple plots in multiple windows

Tags: plot, gnuplot, gnu

I want to do multiple plots related to differents data columns of the same file but I want a new window for each plot. I don't want attached plots associated to the command `set multiplot layout 1,2`.
The idea is represented by the following pseudocode:

```
>gnuplot

>plot "myfile.txt" u 1:4

>#make me plot another file without deleting the previous one i.e. open a new window on which data is plotted

>instructions I don't know

>plot "myfile.txt" u: ($3*$3) 

>#I obtain two windows
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't write which terminal you are using. I understand you want to have two windows next to each other, and not two graph as file on disk. In gnuplot console check for example: `help wxt`. In case you want two files on disk you have to select another terminal, e.g.

```
set term pngcairo
set output 'myOutput1.png'
plot x
set output 'myOutput2.png'
plot x**2
set output
```

So with the interactive wxt terminal the following works for me:

**Code:**

```
### several terminals
reset session

set term wxt 1 size 500,400
plot sin(x)

set term wxt 2 size 500,300
plot cos(x)

set term wxt 3 size 300,200
plot x**2

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I am on Ubuntu, not Windows versions of Gnuplot or Virtual boxes.

Comment: Then, you can use eg. `set term qt 0`, `set term qt 1` etc.